# How to reduce react-redux boilerplate - I try creating a ComponentFactory but I'm getting react-redux errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I thought of creating a factory function called `createScreen` for reducing the boilerplate required by `react-redux`.

It looks like this:

**ParentScreenFactory.js**

```
export default function createScreen(stateActions = []) {
  class ParentScreen extends React.Component {

  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      ...state,
    };
  }

  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    const creators = Map()
            .merge(...stateActions)
            .filter(value => typeof value === 'function')
            .toObject();

    return {
      actions: bindActionCreators(creators, dispatch),
      dispatch,
    };
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ParentScreen);
}
```

**Child.js**

```
const ParentScreen = createScreen([
  routingActions,
  authActions,
]);

class Child extends ParentScreen {

  constructor(props) {   // <-- error on this line
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View/>
    );
  }
}
export default Child;
```

for some reason though, I get `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'context.store')`.
Stacktrace:

```
Connect(ParentScreen)
connect.js:129
```

which is this line of code `_this.store = props.store || context.store;`.
Any obvious mistakes you see here?
Other than that do you have any better idea about how to reduce all that boilerplate code?

Thank you.

Comment: Your title is completely irrelevant to your question. You ask a question about how to fix an error and throw in "how can I reduce the boilerplate" at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything will be simpler if you work with the actual component class, rather than trying to extend the empty connected one ([this is the class you're actually extending](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/connect.js#L75-L341)).

If you want your component to work predictably, then you need to connect your component directly. Try returning a function from your factory instead.

```
export default function createScreen(stateActions = []) {
  return (Component) => {
    // ...
    return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);
  };
}
```

Then your instantiation starts to look something like this.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

const ParentScreen = createScreen([
  routingActions,
  authActions,
]);

export default ParentScreen(Child);
```

If you want to share some behaviour between all components, then you're better off using a higher-order-component.

```
function withCommonBehaviour(Component) {
  return (props) => {
    let newProps = doSomething(props);
    return <Component {...newProps} />;
  };
}
```

Then just hook that up inside your `createScreen` function.

```
// ...
let CommonComponent = withCommonBehaviour(Component);
return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CommonComponent);
```

Comment: That actually looks good, but is there a way to run stuff on the constructor of the parent component as well?
That's something I forgot to mention, but I need it.

Comment: I don't think I understand what the "parent component" is.

Comment: Ok lets say I want my Child component to always have some boilerplate code running within it's constructor like so:

class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){ /*do something here*/ }
}

can I skip writing that over and over again for each child I create using your suggestion? Perhaps by adding that boilerplate code inside the `createScreen` method?

Comment: It really depends what you want to do, but sharing behaviours between components is something that would be best handled with a [higher order component](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.karo75qyy).

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thank you for that answer.